# Uncaught AssertionError: expected {} to equal 'testing'

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai, supertest

I'm not sure why it's saying the object is empty. This is my testing block of code.

```
describe("POST /users", () => {
  let body = {
    name: "testing",
    email: "testing@testing.com",
    password: 123456
  };

  it("Creates a new user", done => {
    request(app)
      .post("/register")
      .send(body)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) return done(err);
        expect(res.body).to.be.equal("testing");
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Is there something I'm missing for the test to recognize the information being passed in? As in the payload since I thought that is what .send(payload) was for.

Thanks for the clarity.

** Update Controller and more information **

// Testing

```
let request = require("supertest");
let expect = require("chai").expect;
let app = require("../../server/server");

describe("GET /test", function() {
  it("Returns a json for testing", done => {
    request(app)
      .get("/test")
      .end((err, res) => {
        done();
      });
  });
});

describe("POST /users", () => {
  let body = {
    name: "testing",
    email: "testing@testing.com",
    password: 123456
  };

  it("Creates a new user", done => {
    request(app)
      .post("/register")
      .send(body)
      .expect(res => {
        expect(res.body).to.be.equal("testing");
      })
      .end(done);
  });
});
```

// User routes

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// Load User Model
const User = require("../../models/User");

// @route GET api/users/test
// @desc Tests user route
// @access Public
router.get("/test", (req, res) => res.json({ msg: "Users Works" }));

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      res.status(409).json({ msg: "User exist" });
    } else {
      const newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
      });

      newUser
        .save()
        .then(user => res.status(200).send(user))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

// Server

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

const users = require("./routes/api/users");

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB Config
const db = require("../config/keys").mongoURI;

// Connect to MongoDB Atlas
mongoose.connect(
  db,
  { useNewUrlParser: true },
  (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error occurred while connecting to MongoDB Atlas...\n", err);
    }
    console.log("Connected...");
  }
);

// Routes
app.use("/api/users", users);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

let server = app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
);

module.exports = server;
```

Comment: The `.send` method seems fine. Your test says you're posting to `/users` but the test itself posts to `/register`. Could this be an issue?

Comment: @mcranston18 Thanks for replying. I should possibly change the description or my route name. In the routes file I have it as router.post("/register", (req, res) etc.

Comment: @mcranston18 If description doesn't match does that cause an error? I thought the .post is what matters with what route you'll be testing. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Description definitely does not cause an error. Could you post relevant details of your routes/controller file? Could you also confirm that a POST to `/register` works as expected when you do it manually?

Comment: Also, assuming you're using Supertest, could you update your test like this: https://gist.github.com/mcranston18/00f9d4916b2242e2539553dc68ba2656

Comment: @mcranston18 I've changed the test as you've recommended but still receive the same error. I've also included my server file, testing, and controller for the user routes. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: @mcranston18 Regarding confirming if it works. Before I started to write the test I checked with Postman and it worked without a problem. This is my first time ever using test (everyone says I need to learn and I'm putting a lot into trying to learn). Hope you can point out where I went wrong and how to further improve. Thank you again.